# In certain cases, can UPDATE transactions fail rather than block waiting for "FOR UPDATE lock"?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I'm using Postgres 9.6.5.

The docs say:

> [13.3. Explicit Locking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/explicit-locking.html)
>
> **13.3.2. Row-level Locks" -> "Row-level Lock Modes" -> "FOR UPDATE":**
>
> FOR UPDATE causes the rows retrieved by the SELECT statement to be locked as though for update. This prevents them from being locked, modified or deleted by other transactions until the current transaction ends. That is, other transactions that attempt UPDATE, DELETE, SELECT FOR UPDATE, SELECT FOR NO KEY UPDATE, SELECT FOR SHARE or SELECT FOR KEY SHARE of these rows will be blocked until the current transaction ends; conversely, SELECT FOR UPDATE will wait for a concurrent transaction that has run any of those commands on the same row, and will then lock and return the updated row (or no row, if the row was deleted). ...
>
> The  mode is also acquired by any DELETE on a row, and also by an UPDATE that modifies the values on certain columns. Currently, the set of columns considered for the UPDATE case are those that have a unique index on them that can be used in a foreign key (so partial indexes and expressional indexes are not considered), but this may change in the future.

Regarding UPDATEs on rows that are locked via "SELECT FOR UPDATE" in another transaction, I read the above as follows: other transactions that attempt UPDATE of these rows will be blocked until the current transaction ( which did "SELECT FOR UPDATE" for those rows ) ends, unless the columns in these rows being UPDATE'ed are those that don't have a unique index on them that can be used in a foreign key.

Is this correct ? If so, if I have a table "program" with a text column "stage" ( this column doesn't fit "have a unique index on them that can be used in a foreign key" ), and I have a transaction that does "SELECT FOR UPDATE" for some rows followed by UPDATE'ing "stage" in these rows, is it correct that other concurrent transactions UPDATE'ing "stage" on these rows can fail, rather than block until the former transaction ends ?

Comment: What exception does the failed UPDATEs show?

Comment: I haven't encountered an exception. I want to know if this can happen under the conditions I described.

Answer (score 0):

Your transactions can fail if a deadlock is detected in one of the `UPDATE` or `SELECT...FOR UPDATE`, for example:

### Transaction 1

`BEGIN;
    SELECT * FROM T1 FOR UPDATE;
    SELECT * FROM T2 FOR UPDATE;
-- Intentionally, no rollback nor commit yet`

### Transaction 2

`BEGIN;
    SELECT * FROM T2 FOR UPDATE; -- blocks T2 first
    SELECT * FROM T1 FOR UPDATE; -- exception will happen here`

The moment the second transaction tries to lock `T1` you'll get:

`ERROR:  40P01: deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 15981 waits for ShareLock on transaction 3538264; blocked by process 15942.
Process 15942 waits for ShareLock on transaction 3538265; blocked by process 15981.
HINT:  See server log for query details.
CONTEXT:  while locking tuple (0,1) in relation "t1"
LOCATION:  DeadLockReport, deadlock.c:956
Time: 1001.728 ms`

Comment: Thanks, but by "certain cases", I'm referring to "columns to update don't have a unique index on them that can be used in a foreign key"; I'm trying to determine whether I'm interpreting their documentation correctly. Hard to express this in the question header, so the details are in the body. Lmk if you have suggestions on how I could've made the question header more clear.

Comment: When that documentation mentions foreign keys, it is only referring to issuing a DELETE on another table that has a foreign key to the table where you did the SELECT FOR UPDATE. What they mean is that such DELETE will also lock. There is no mention in the docs you posted about any kind of failure, just mentions of locking.

Comment: I'm not saying there is a mention in the docs I posted about any kind of failure. The docs state: "The mode is also acquired ..., and ALSO BY AN UPDATE that modifies the values on certain columns. Currently, the set of columns considered for the UPDATE case are those that have a unique index on them that can be used in a foreign key (so partial indexes and expressional indexes are not considered), but this may change in the future." Given that, please see the last paragraph of my question.